# How to resolve HttpClient exists in multiple libs

Tags: c#, .net-core, dotnet-httpclient, .net-standard-2.0

I'm trying to use the [IdentityModel](https://www.nuget.org/packages/IdentityModel/) package in a .NET Core class library but I get a conflict between `netstandard` and `System.Net.Http`:

```
error CS0433: The type 'HttpClient' exists in both
'System.Net.Http, Version=4.1.1.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' and
'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'
```

The project file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="IdentityModel" Version="2.8.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

The default `Class1.cs`:

```
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
namespace Test
{
    public class Class1
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        public Class1() {}
    }
}
```

What's the right way to resolve this issue?

Comment: is it runtime error?

Comment: No it's compile time `dotnet build`

Comment: if they are in different namespaces, how about add namespaces before the class name?

Comment: They both use the same namespace, System.Net.Http.

Comment: I'm having the same issue porting existing dll to .net standared 2.0. I guess IdentityModel should refer .net standared library meta package instead of individual packages. But I'm not quite sure.

Comment: I raised the issue here. https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel2/issues/49

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem recently while trying to use HttpClient in a Xamarin project. To resolve, I added a configuration file and redirected to a specific version of System.Net.Http. The same might work for you but you have to pick the version you want to use "2.0.0.0" vs "4.1.1.1". Contents of app.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.1.1" newVersion="4.1.1.1" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I'm not sure that's the same issue? Were there conflicting libraries, each with System.Net.Http.HttpClient? Also I'm trying to create a class lib for nuget. Not sure how an app.config fits with that scenario.

Comment: I had conflicts with version 4.1.1.1 and an older version (can't remember) so I couldn't use HttpClient and couldn't compile. I'm not sure if it applies to a library though.

Comment: I have the same error with an asp.net core / .net standard 1.4 application. This fix is not working with web.config.

Comment: By closing Visual Studio, deleting the bin and obj folder and restarting and rebuilding, I was able to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer but dirty workaround. Hopefully, help someone to troubleshoot the actual issue.

1. locate global NuGet package location

   `dotnet nuget locals all -l`

   On my machine it is located in `C:\Users\{user}\.nuget\packages\`
2. Edit the `{package-location}\IdentityModel\2.8.1\identitymodel.nuspec`.
   Modify target framework to refere `.netstandared2.0` instead of `.netstandared1.4` and Remove or comment out `<dependency id="System.Net.Http" version="4.3.2" exclude="Build,Analyzers" />` line under `.netstandard2.0` target framework.

   ```xml
   <group targetFramework=".NETStandard2.0">
       <dependency id="NETStandard.Library" version="1.6.1" exclude="Build,Analyzers" />
       <dependency id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="9.0.1" exclude="Build,Analyzers" />
       <!--<dependency id="System.Net.Http" version="4.3.2" exclude="Build,Analyzers" />-->
       <dependency id="System.ValueTuple" version="4.3.1" exclude="Build,Analyzers" />
       <dependency id="System.Security.Claims" version="4.3.0" exclude="Build,Analyzers" />
       <dependency id="System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms" version="4.3.0" exclude="Build,Analyzers" />
       <dependency id="System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates" version="4.3.0" exclude="Build,Analyzers" />
   </group>
   ```
3. `dotnet restore`
4. `dotnet build`

Now the sample should build.

Comment: Apparently this has been fixed in the latest versions of `IdentityModel`, but still good to know for other problematic packages.